# How to disable os_log debug messages, for certain categories or subsystems?

Tags: ios, logging

I'm using the unified logging API in my iOS app.

```
import os
private let log = OSLog(subsystem: "", category: "ThisComponent")
...
os_log(.debug, log:log, "Blah blah blah: %@", str)
```

Those debug log calls show up in the Xcode console when running my app. Once I'm no longer focused on a particular component, I don't want to see its flood of debug level log messages. Is there a way to disable them with an environment variable or something like that? Or do I need to change the code by either commenting them out, or defining my own `Bool` vars and adding `if` checks:

```
if isDebugLogging {
    os_log(.debug, log:log, ...)
}
```

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) mention being able to do this for macOS, but I'm specifically asking about iOS.

I don't want to shut it *all* off. For this to be useful I need a way to shut it off by subsystem or category.

Comment: Added an example to the first part of my answer, I think that pretty well solves it eh.

Answer (score 3):

You are applying `os_log` by specifying some global OSLog object. Just replace that object by `OSLog.disabled`, and now messages sent through it won't go anywhere.

Example:

```
let _activeLog = OSLog(subsystem: "hey", category: "ho")
let _inactiveLog = OSLog.disabled
var heyHoEnabled = true
var myLog : OSLog { heyHoEnabled ? _activeLog : _inactiveLog }
```

So now:

```
    os_log(.debug, log: myLog, "hey") // logged
    os_log(.debug, log: myLog, "ho") // logged
    self.heyHoEnabled = false
    os_log(.debug, log: myLog, "hey nonny no") // not logged
```

---

But let's say you still want to send the messages; you just don't to *see* them. There is no way to say, at the console level, "do *not* show me certain messages". You can filter the console, but only by what you *want*, not what you *don't* want.

By the way, the fact that `os_log` messages go into the Xcode console is a secondary feature. The *primary* place they appear is the Console application. And the Console messages can be filtered so as to include only the subsystems or categories you want. This is a very powerful filter, much more powerful and precise than the Xcode console.

So if *all* of your console messages are `os_log` messages, with different subsystems or categories, then you can use the Console application to filter in very powerful ways.

Comment: The Console app is great, but it gives me one big problem - it hammers my CPU when I'm using it to observe an app in that way. Do you see that too? Maybe my laptop (2012 Macbook Pro) is getting too old. By the way, I think you can ask it to _not_ show you certain messages, at least in some ways. If I control click on the table/list area I get a menu with "Show ..." and "Hide ..." filters.

Comment: Oooo it sounds even cooler than I thought. :) I knew it was a lot more powerful but I didn't realize it could do that.